# Negating a string while matching others

Tags: r, regex, string

I would like to match some strings using regex while negating others in R. In the below example, I would like exclude subsections of strings that I would otherwise like to match. Example below using the answer from [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word).

My confusion is that when I try this, grepl throws an error:

Error in grepl(mypattern, mystring) : 
  invalid regular expression 'boardgames|(^((?!games).)*$)', reason 'Invalid regexp'

```
mypattern <- "boardgames|(^((?!games).)*$)"
mystring <- c("boardgames", "boardgames", "games")

grepl(mypattern, mystring)
```

Note running using str_detect returns desired results (i.e. T, T, F), but I would like to use grepl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `perl = TRUE` as the default option is `perl = FALSE`

```
grepl(mypattern, mystring, perl = TRUE)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

This is needed when `Perl-compatible regexps` are used

According to `?regexp`

> The perl = TRUE argument to grep, regexpr, gregexpr, sub, gsub and
>   strsplit switches to the PCRE library that implements regular
>   expression pattern matching using the same syntax and semantics as
>   Perl 5.x, with just a few differences.